# Deadlock in main thread when use semaphore ObjC

Tags: objective-c, deadlock

I am new to Xcode and ObjectiveC and I am building a non-UI tool. I found my main thread will get hang forever and never wakeup when I am using semaphore in main thread

```
      dispatch_semaphore_t waitSem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // do something else
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(waitSem);

      });

      dispatch_wait(waitSem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Comment: That's how semaphores work. It seems that you are going to force something asynchronous to become synchronous. Don't do that. Please learn to understand asynchronous data processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No async tasks will be processed on the main queue while it is blocking inside `dispatch_wait()`. This includes the task that you queued.

`dispatch_wait()` from the main queue only makes sense if the semaphore condition will be met without the main queue running any code.